# iterm jump word in path

Tags: path, keyboard-shortcuts, cpu-word, iterm2

I'm trying to navigate by word in the following, for instance:

Dir1/Dir2/DirA/Dir4/File

I want to be able to jump forward/backward by word, and potentially replace DirA by Dir3.

in iterm profile settings, I have mapped keyboard shortcut (option+delete(backspace)) currently to send escape+b. if cursor is at end of line, instead of jumping backward by a word, cursor moves all the way to the beginning of the path, i.e. to the beginning of Dir1. How do I get it to navigate by "word"?

Comment: sorry, I meant i've mapped (option + left arrow). to send escape+b.